# I have a question about MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed (AtlasError / HandshakeError / ResetPool)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

First of all, please understand that there may be some difficulties in delivering the contents due to my poor English skills.

When I want to run nodemon, termial showed this error.

```
MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\twinc\Desktop\230102\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:230:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\twinc\Desktop\230102\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:61:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\twinc\Desktop\230102\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:125:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\twinc\Desktop\230102\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError',
  connectionGeneration: 0,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
```

In Postman, it showed like this.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "err": {}
}
```

This is what I wrote. (index.js)
I covered some personal information to show you.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { User } = require('./model/User');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0.xxx.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase', {
}).then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(arr => console.log(arr))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, Express!')
})

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);

  user.save((err, userInfo) => {
    if(err) return res.json({ success: false, err});
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
})
```

This is User.js file.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        maxLength: 50,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        unique: 1,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        minLength: 50,
    },
    role: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    image: String,
    token: {
        type: String,
    },
    tokenExp: {
        type: Number,
    },
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = { User }
```

I hope I can get

```
{
      success: true,
    }
```

Comment: Your connection to MongoDB has been failed. Where did you get the `mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0.xxx.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase` connection string ?

Comment: As I said, I don't reveal my personal information. name, password, xxx are string that replaces my information.

Comment: I don't need those exact values, where did you get the connection string , from MongodbAtlas or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. I got the connection from MongodbAtlas.

Comment: Have you limited api access, for example by restricting ip?

Comment: @pierpy Maybe not. Is there a way to limit it by using MongoDB?

Comment: @JOO yes, under Security-> Network access in Atlas dashboard

Comment: @pierpy I see IP Access List, Peering, Private Endpoint on this page. On which page can I limit the ip? I searched on Google but I can not get right answer.

Comment: https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-atlas-login-ip-whitelisting/#how-to-whitelist-ip-addresses-on-mongodb-atlas

Comment: Add your IP to the white list IP list, or you can add all ips On the left side of the screen under SECURITY, click on Network Access.
Click the green Add IP Address button.
In the modal, click the ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE button. You should see 0.0. 0.0/0 in the Access List Entry field.
Click the green Confirm button.